# When one SQL table is linked to another table, is it impossible to delete the data from the database?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

There are three tables linked to each other as in the diagram. [image: Diagram]
This Youtuber is using IsDeleted=0 or IsDeleted=1 column to indicate that the data in the table is deleted or not.

When one SQL table is linked to another table, is it impossible to delete the data from the database? If it is impossible, then I think its really bad. Isn't there any workarounds for completely deleting the data?

Also, maybe Facebook also does something like IsDeleted=1 and they don't let us see us our own data when we 'delete' it while they can still access our past interests. What do you think?

Comment: If you are trying to delete data from the second table, that won't be a problem. If you try to delete the data in the primary table and the second table has a foreign key relationship with the first table, entity framework throws error while deleting.

Comment: I'm more confused by the relationship that an employee has many sites, but an site only has one employee. I wonder what a "site" is.

Comment: @Larnu Site is the workplace. Someone may be employeed in Head office in San Hose, someone other may be employed in the factory in Nevada. So on and so forth. Yeah. I think this should be one to one relationship. I think, I have screwed up there.

Comment: I actually think the relationship should be other way round. A site has many employees; not an employee has many sites. Unless you have a head office with only one employee...

Answer (score 0):

No, data can always be deleted from a database.  There may be constraints what has to happen before the data gets deleted (permissions, foreign-key constraints, etc), but it eventually can be deleted.

A column such as that is frequently used for maintaining data history in the application.  The "links" you refer to are called Foreign Key relationships and they are used to maintain integrity within relational data.  The IsDeleted column in the resultset doesn't have anything to do with the FK.

Also, that column would not indicate that the *table* is deleted, but rather the row of data the values of the column belong to.

Answer (score 0):

Well defined and static and structured arrangement of data is one of the most important things in relational databases. In the tables you show, Employee belongs to a department. Now if you delete the department, you have a broken record in the Employee table. This is why, SQL will not allow you to delete the department.

To solve this, you will need to either stop the deletion of department with message like "There are users in this department. Cannot be deleted." or remove the department id (set it to null) from the employee records which belong to this department.

There are situations, business needs where the data is to be retained for various reasons. In those cases, `IsActive` like flags come to rescue. The records can be filtered using them and thus are hidden on the screen. This is generally referred to as soft delete.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, i think it is very good practice to do Soft Delete rather than hard delete because you can safely recover the data later. To your question you can only delete parent table data if there are no more child table data. Else you get this errror:

```
the delete statement conflicted with the reference constraint ...
```

for example in your database say you have data of employee and departments. e.g this is your department table:

```
ID  DepartmentName
1      HR
2      marketing
```

and this is your employee table:

```
ID DepartmentId  Name      Address
1     1         Name1      address1
2     1         Name2      address2
3     1         Name3      address3
```

Now if you want to delete marketing department from Department table , you can delete it easily and there is no error. But now if you try to delete HR department you will get error as mentioned above because the HR department Id(i.e. 1) is already linked with another table called Employee table. So if you want to delete HR department anyhow, you must first delete all the record from employee table with DepartmentId=1 . otherwise you can use the approach as the youtuber you mentioned.
Hope it helps !

Comment: Thanks. That really helped although someone donated dislike to my question. :(